# find highest tag with version number

Tags: git

I would like to checkout the highest version number and checkout that branch.

Currently I am doing:

```
git checkout $(git describe --tags $(git rev-list --tags --max-count=1))
```

But when the latest tag was 3.7.1 I will checkout this instead of another version which have the version number 4.0.1.

How can I make sure to checkout the highest version number?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are able to sort tags by semantic version names:

```
$ git checkout $(git tag -l --sort -version:refname | head -n 1)
```

Comment: Looks like this the opposite of what the OP want's.